# ng-bootstrap's Carousel not looking right in full window but looks good on minimum

Tags: css, angular, carousel, angular7, ng-bootstrap

i am learning about ng-bootstrap and was really looking into using their implementation of carousel. I went to their official document and the example they have work for half-window but doesn't look good in full window. How can i make the carousel look good in full window?

I tried assigning `ngb-carousel` an id and changing its display to inline but it didn't work.

link(listed below) takes you to official doc and if you click on StackBlitz at the top u can run the code. (sorry i tried to provide link to stackBlitz's example here but it kept on redirecting to homepage).

link to offical doc  (i am usnig FIRST EXAMPLE's code!!!!):
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples

Here is the copied code:
app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { NgbdCarouselBasic } from './carousel-basic';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, NgbModule],
  declarations: [NgbdCarouselBasic],
  exports: [NgbdCarouselBasic],
  bootstrap: [NgbdCarouselBasic]
})
export class NgbdCarouselBasicModule {}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <hr>

  <p>
    This is a demo example forked from the <strong>ng-bootstrap</strong> project: Angular powered Bootstrap.
    Visit <a href="https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/" target="_blank">https://ng-bootstrap.github.io</a> for more widgets and demos.
  </p>

  <hr>

  <ngbd-carousel-basic></ngbd-carousel-basic>
</div>
```

carousel-basic.html

```
<ngb-carousel *ngIf="images">
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <img [src]="images[0]" alt="Random first slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>First slide label</h3>
      <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <img [src]="images[1]" alt="Random second slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Second slide label</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <img [src]="images[2]" alt="Random third slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Third slide label</h3>
      <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

carouselbasic.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({selector: 'ngbd-carousel-basic', templateUrl: './carousel-basic.html'})
export class NgbdCarouselBasic implements OnInit {
  images: Array<string>;

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._http.get('https://picsum.photos/list')
        .pipe(map((images: Array<{id: number}>) => this._randomImageUrls(images)))
        .subscribe(images => this.images = images);
  }

  private _randomImageUrls(images: Array<{id: number}>): Array<string> {
    return [1, 2, 3].map(() => {
      const randomId = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)].id;
      return `https://picsum.photos/900/500?image=${randomId}`;
    });
  }
}
```

again, it(carousel) looks good in half screen, but looks completely off in full screen(like you can't see the right arrow in carousel). Its responsive but idk what i can do to make it look carousel in full screen.

Ultiamtely, i am trying to add this to my own website and when i try adding it now, the right side of carousel looks completely off(cant see carousel in right side). I am sure if i can resolve the full screen issue with carousel then it will work on my page.

**EDIT**:-----------------------------------
I was not able to sovle this extra margin but i tried to center the ng-carousel and it made it so that the left and right icons do appear together.

Comment: Hi Amit, does the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 CSS changes to meet your requirements:

```
.carouselImage { width:100%;  }
::ng-deep .container-fluid { padding:0 !important; }
```

the first one ensures that the width is 100% no matter the size of the image... for padding, we just over-ride the paddings which were there because of `container-fluid` class

complete [working demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-afmjvn?file=app%2Fcarousel-basic.ts)